# Switch to Apache Event MPM from Prefork in Debian 8

Tags: debian, apache-2.4, debian-jessie, mpm-prefork

With `a2query -M` command, I found out that Apache 2.4 uses Prefork, so today, I want to switch to Event MPM. I installed Event MPM with `apt-get install apache2-mpm-event` command and restarted Apache as shown [here](https://scottlinux.com/2014/06/18/switch-to-or-enable-apache-event-mpm-in-ubuntu-14-04-for-http-connections/). But `a2query -M` tells me that Prefork is still enabled.

Then, I run `a2dismod mpm_prefork` and `a2enmod mpm_event`. When restarting Apache, there was an error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed. See 'systemctl status apache2.service' and 'jour nalctl -xn' for details.
```

Next, I run `systemctl status apache2.service` which prompts

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─forking.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-04-18 02:13:12 CEST; 32s ago
  Process: 29867 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 11895 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 29961 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: Starting web server: apache2 failed!
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: The apache2 configtest failed. .......
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: Output of config test was:
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: [Tue Apr 18 02:13:12.111084 2017] ....
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost apache2[29961]: The Apache error log may have more....
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exit...=1
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 18 02:13:12 localhost systemd[1]: Unit apache2.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

and `journalctl -xn`

```
-- Logs begin at Tue 2017-04-11 11:38:36 CEST, end at Tue 2017-04-18 02:14:01 CEST. --
Apr 18 02:13:14 localhost sshd[29955]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 02:13:28 localhost sshd[29981]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for 177.64.uzpak.uz [213.230.102.177] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Apr 18 02:13:28 localhost sshd[29981]: Accepted password for root from 213.230.102.177 port 64786 ssh2
Apr 18 02:13:28 localhost sshd[29981]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 02:14:01 localhost CRON[29990]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 02:14:01 localhost CRON[29989]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 18 02:14:01 localhost CRON[29992]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/server.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.
Apr 18 02:14:01 localhost CRON[29991]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/ispconfig/server/cron.sh 2>&1 | while read line; do echo `/bin/date` "$line" >> /var/log/ispconfig/cron.lo
Apr 18 02:14:01 localhost CRON[29989]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 18 02:14:01 localhost CRON[29990]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

I have no idea at what stage I did wrong. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-php-7-on-debian/)  to install the server. Any ideas, recommendations are appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I found this in my apache log:

```
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28858] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.53 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations

[core:notice] [pid 28858] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 28858] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[ 2017-04-18 02:17:19.3278 30199/7f89356db740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nogroup', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/usr/bin/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.53', 'web_server_pid' => '30197', 'web_server_type' => 'apache', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '33', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '33' }
```

Also, `apache2ctl configtest` result is:

```
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-ispconfig.conf:69
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK
```

Comment: If needed I can provide any logs, just mention the file with location

Comment: I also did not find any tutorial on that on Debian 8

Comment: Default error logs are in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.  You can also run `apache2ctl configtest` by hand to see what the error is.  (Or add `-l` to `systemctl status apache2.service` to see the `....` under "output of config test was:")

Comment: @DerfK, I do not understand what in the parenthesis is.

Comment: `systemctl status apache2.service -l`